# Check if Entry widget is selected

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, touchscreen, raspberry-pi3

I'm making a program on the Raspberry Pi with a touchscreen display. 
I'm using Python Tkinter that has two entry widgets and one on screen keypad. I want to use the same keypad for entering data on both entry widgets.

Can anyone tell me how can i check if an entry is selected? Similar like clicking on the Entry using the mouse and the cursor appears. How can I know that in Python Tkinter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a widget with the keyboard focus. You can query that with the `focus_get` method of the root window. It will return whatever widget has keyboard focus. That is the window that should receive input from your keypad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use events and bindigs to catch FocusIn events for your entries.

```
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

def callback_entry1_focus(event):
    print 'entry1 focus in'

def callback_entry2_focus(event):
    print 'entry2 focus in'

entry1.bind("<FocusIn>", callback_entry1_focus)
entry2.bind("<FocusIn>", callback_entry2_focus)
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Both worked, but i used the <FocusIn>, because it immediately calls the callback function, make it very handy. Thank you for your help